# Access Query - Count(*) as sl_no order by is not working?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a access query contains `count(*)` to select as like `Row_Number()`, but the order by is not working like the expected result.

My Query :

```
Select 
    (
        select 
            count(*) 
        from 
            partymst 
        where 
            pt.ID>=ID order by pt.pty_name) as sl_no,
            pt.* from partymst as pt order by pt.pty_name
```

The above statement is giving like the following Output.

```
Sl-No Name 
2     Maheswaran & Co
3     Pollachi Thatha & co
1     Pollachi Kodi Thatha
```

So, how to achieve the `sl_no` by 1,2,3

Thanks for Guidances.

Comment: Try this   `order by  sl_no`

Comment: You can just specify the column no in order by `order by 1`

Answer (score 0):

This seems the correct one -

> pt.* from partymst as pt order by sl_no

Comment: OLeDb Exception was unhndled - No value given for one or more required parameters Thankyou